# Can't understand this division algorithm in Computer Architecture

Tags: computer-architecture

So, I'm preparing for an exam where I have solve divisions using this division algorithm:

[image]

While I understand the theory (image above), I couldn't understand this example below:

[image]

My problem is with the "First Step", apparently you place the dividend in the "Remainder" box but I don't undetrsand how did they come up with the divisor (10 000), where did this number come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divisor is the 2 put into the upper 4 bits of the 8 bit divisor register.